# How do I add multiple unique keys in a table using memsql?

Tags: singlestore

Using MemSQL I want to create a table which has multiple unique keys and 1 primary key in it. But I don't know how do I add multiple unique keys in table. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_auth` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `rest_code` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pswd_updated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And I wanted add unique key on `user_id,code,rest_code` columns.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a shard key on enough columns that every unique/primary key contains the shard key.  If you dont specify a shard key, the primary key is chosen, and since (user_id, code, rest_code) isn't part of the shard key (implicitly on id), it won't work.  This is because MemSQL needs to be able to resolve duplicates locally, that is, within a single shard.

I would try something like `shard(user_id), primary key(user_id, id), unqiue key(user_id, code, rest_code)`.  Yes, adding `user_id` to the primary key is redundant, and I'm making some assumptions about your app, but my guess is the database doesn't actually have to worry about multiple users "claiming the same id", so this will work.

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried your solution but Memsql generates both primary key ,unique key as a composite key and I added unique keys on multiple columns as u suggested those also created as a composite unique key.  I wanted to maintain uniqueness of each column not a composite unique key.